# Pardot : How to get set of prospects based on custom field from Pardot API?

Tags: salesforce, b2b, pardot

We have 200 prospects in Pardot account and trying to use Pardot API to fetch the prospects on custom fields.

Tried below API query to get records from Prospect,

https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/query?user_key=0flfsadfrerfsffrwaefwe&api_key=f90lfjmejfumdjfmdjk8&fst_Permitted_Contact=yes

Above query not considering Custom Field Filter instead its giving all the Prospect Result Set.

Is there a way to get the result set based on Custom Field?

Answer (score 0):

Custom fields are not currently supported as Supported Search Criteria.  Please reference http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-3/prospects/ or http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-4/prospects/ for more details.

An option could be to create a dynamic list with your search criteria, then use the API to query based on `list_id`. Just keep in mind there is a delay in prospects matching/unmatching criteria.